# Query params are not working in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, express-handlebars

Here is my code :

```
    app.get("/editar-equipo?:id", (req, res) => {
    
    const equipos = obtenerEquipos()
    let equipoSeleccionado 
    
    for(let i = 0; i < equipos.length; i++){
        if(equipos[i].numeroId === Number(req.query.id)){
            equipoSeleccionado = equipos[i]
        }
    }
    
    

res.render("edit-team", {
        layout: "header", 
           data: {
               equipoSeleccionado
        }
    })
})
```

And my handlebars html is

```
 <td>
    <form id="editar-equipo" method="GET" action="/editar-equipo?id={{equipo.numeroId}}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
    </form>
  </td>
```

and the buttons are created well:

```
<form id="editar-equipo" method="GET" action="/editar-equipo?id=58">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
    </form>
```

But when i click the button it doesn't work. It loads

```
> http://localhost:3030/editar-equipo?
```

But if i manually write http://localhost:3030/editar-equipo?id=58 in the url bar it works correctly and the teams loads normally.

Any help? Is there any other parameter missing? Or something like that?

Im using express-handlebars and express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already test your case. Browser delete all query after question mark. So you need to put an hidden `input` inside your `form` element:

```
<form id="editar-equipo" method="GET" action="/editar-equipo">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="58">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
</form>
```